# Angular 6 - Handle multiple duplicate API calls

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table in my page which displays order details, client ids and client names. The names are fetched through external api call which usually takes 20+ seconds to return the response.

**The problem**

Lets say I have 20 orders to be displayed in the table, some of which are placed by the same clients. So, lets assume 8 clients may have placed those 20 orders. Ideally I should be placing 8 api calls to fetch the 8 names. Since the code logic is handled using `*ngFor`, there are 20 api calls placed. How can I ensure to place only 8 calls?

**What I have tried**

I tried storing the names in client side session and placing api calls only if it does not exist in session. The problem with this logic is that all the 20 api call threads are initiated before the first response is stored in the session.

Need help.

Comment: What data do you already have before sending out those 20 requests?

Comment: @mbojko I have all the data except client names. I cannot store client names in my database. The api expects client codes and returns client name in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show any code, so I'm going to assume you have an array of twenty order objects, having at least these fields:

```
export interface Order {
  orderId: string;
  clientId: string;
  // Add other stuff as needed
}
```

Then in your service, you have this field and you assign it in your `subscribe` handler.

```
orders: Order[];
```

Okay, good.

I would determine the unique `clientId` values using this:

```
const clientSet = new Set(this.orders.map(order => order.clientId));
const clientIds = [...clientSet];
```

Line 1 creates a new array containing only the `clientId` values (using the `map` function) and uses that to creates a new `Set` object.

Line 2 turns that `Set` into a new array, which will only contain unique values.

With all this covered, I want to mention something about doing this and performance.

Your twenty orders may have been for eight clients, but they may also have been for twenty, or you could have ten thousand orders. So even if you reduce the list of clients as I showed, making separate web calls for all of them is still not great. If you have any control over the API at all, just use a method that accepts an array of `clientID` values, so you can do one single call instead of (potentially) many. Or better yet, return all the info you need in the initial call that gives you the orders.

Comment: Thanks Cobus. This is a good idea. I really do not have any control over the external api or else I would have implemented a bulk fetch method. Anyway, the table is paginated to display 50 orders at max, so no worries on that part.

Answer (score 0):

A rough unpolished idea: on receiving the list of orders with client IDs, you can create in the component a local dictionary of (observables of) customer names:

```
interface CustomerDictionary {
    [key: string]: Observable<string>;
}

//...
customerDictionary: CustomerDictionary = {}
```

Collect all the customer IDs in the table, and populate the dictionary with requests

```
collectedCustomerIDs.forEach(
    id => this.customerDictionary[id] = receiveCustomerNameFromAPI(id).pipe(shareReplay(1))
);
```

(Also, caching it somehow, globally, application-wide, might be a good idea).

Consume it in the template by `customerDictionary[id] | async`.